# How to upload a file to server via POST API in Yii2.0?

Tags: php, yii2

I make a model in yii2 from this link
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html
I post the file using POST request to API and got all file information in my controller but unable to upload file using this Yii2.0 model created using above link normal PHP file upload code work fine.
Here is my controller code

```
public function actionUploadFile()
    {
        $upload = new UploadForm();
        var_dump($_FILES);

        $upload->imageFile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        //$upload->imageFile = $_FILES;
        var_dump($upload->upload());
    }
```

and my model code is

```
class UploadForm extends Model
    {
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $imageFile;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFile'], 'safe'],
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        try {
            if ($this->validate()) {
                $this->imageFile->saveAs('/var/www/html/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
                var_dump("Jeree");
                return true;
            } else {
                var_dump($this->getErrors());
                return false;
            }
        }catch (ErrorException $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: show your model, and controller please

Comment: I change the question if you have any method to overcome it then let me know

Comment: I'm not an exper but why you use $_files and not $_post?. and  '/var/wwww/html/' is an absolute path and not a relative path... and 'wwww'  4w? is right?

Comment: if file uploaded successfully then I make the path relative,But as per my knowledge we receive the file type input in $_FILES so I used $_FILES,If I used traditional php method then its working fine but only not with Yii2 model

Comment: please tell me the file name and type you are trying to  uploading

Comment: jpg file,I got the file information and file in $_FILES

Comment: and calling the function via POST method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92423/discussion-between-anway-kulkarni-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
public function actionUpload()
{
   $model = new UploadForm();

   if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
       $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

       if ($model->validate()) {                
          $model->file->saveAs('/var/www/html/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
       }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}
```