# File Not uploading in yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii2

I want to upload an image and save it into my database.
Here, the field name in database is `image_path`. When, I am trying to upload my image it shows an error: Call to a member function `saveAs()` on a non-object on line

```
$customer->file->saveAs('uploads/customer/' . $customer->file->baseName . '.' . $customer->file->extension);
```

If I print `var_dump($customer->file);` it returns **NULL**.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

**This is my view:**

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'my-profile',
            'action' => \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/myprofile', 'id_customer' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id_customer]),                     
            'options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']
    ]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($customer, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**This is my Model:**

```
public $file;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['active', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
        ['active', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],            
        [['file'],'file'],
        [['name', 'image_path'], 'string', 'max' => 200],            
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [            
        'file' => 'Profile Picture ',            
    ];
}
```

**This is my controller:**

```
public function actionMyprofile(){   

  $customer->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($customer,'image_path');      
  $customer->file->saveAs('uploads/customer/' . $customer->file->baseName . '.' . $customer->file->extension);
  $customer->file = 'uploads/customer/' . $customer->file->baseName . '.' . $customer->file->extension;
}
```

Comment: Replace `image_path` with `file` in controller, see your model rules.

Comment: `UploadedFile::getInstance($customer,'image_path');` should be `UploadedFile::getInstance($customer,'file');`, since `<?= $form->field($customer, 'file')->fileInput() ?>`

Comment: I ask a some question some days ago but did not get the acurate answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119257/how-to-upload-a-file-to-server-via-post-api-in-yii2-0

Comment: After doing this it remains same.

Comment: Please, show `var_dump(ini_get('file_uploads'))`, `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: Set full path in saveAs function with alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'my-profile',
        'action' => \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/myprofile', 'id_customer' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id_customer]),                     
        'options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']
]); ?>
<?= $form->field($customer, 'image_path')->fileInput() ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**Model:**

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    ['active', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
    ['active', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],            
    [['image_path'],'file'],
    [['name', 'image_path'], 'string', 'max' => 200],            
  ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
   return [            
       'image_path' => 'Profile Picture ',            
   ];
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new YourModel_name();          

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->image_path = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image_path');

        $filename = pathinfo($model->image_path , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $ext = pathinfo($model->image_path , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $newFname = $filename.'.'.$ext;

        $path=Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/image/event-picture/';
        if(!empty($newFname)){
            $model->image_path->saveAs($path.$newFname);
            $model->image_path = $newFname; 
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['your redirect_path', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }       
        }           
    } 
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```