# how can I upload file in php in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I was trying to upload pdf file from backend but I receive the following error:

> Call to a member function saveAs() for uploading pdf file

My **_form** page

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pdf_file')->fileInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

My **controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Bangle();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
          // echo "<pre>";print_r($_Files['image']);exit;
          $imageName = "special_image_".rand();
          $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

          if(!empty($model->image)){          

             $model->image->saveAs('images/gold/bangle/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->image->extension);

             $model->image = $imageName.'.'.$model->image->extension;
           }

             $pdfName = "my_pdf_".rand();

           if($model->pdf_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'pdf_file')){          

                $model->image->saveAs('pdf/gold/'.$pdfName.'.'.$model->pdf_file->extension);

                $model->pdf_file = $pdfName.'.'.$model->image->extension;
            }

            if($model->save(false))
            {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

            }
            else
            {
                       return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);

            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266454/file-not-uploading-in-yii2/34281464#34281464

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Not uploading in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266454/file-not-uploading-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure your file is post by adding enctype:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
```

2) add rule file to your rules like this:

```
[['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
```

3) Get Instance for model

```
$model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
```

4) use saveAs

```
$model->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName)
```